# Does emmeans use lm_robust cluster-robust standard errors when calculating confidence intervals for transformed outcome variables?

Tags: r, emmeans

I'm examining interactions between two continuous predictor variables using the `emmeans` package. I'm using `lm_robust()` from the `estimatr` package to perform the linear regression and obtain cluster-robust standard errors. The outcome variable is centered and scaled to SD unit variance. For example:

`fit <- lm_robust(scale(Y) ~ X1 * X2 + X3 + X4, data = mydata, cluster = school, se_type = 'CR2')`

I can then perform pairwise contrasts or visualise the lines at three levels of `X2` using code similar to:

```
emmip(fit, X2 ~ X1, CIs = TRUE, at = list(X2 = c(mean(X2) - sd(X2),
                                                 mean(X2),
                                                 mean(X2) + sd(X2))))
```

I do not wish to back transform the outcome variable to its original scale.

My question is whether `emmeans` uses the cluster-robust standard errors to calculate the confidence intervals or the p-values that it reports and does this behaviour depend on whether the outcome variable is on its original scale or transformed? A short example on the `estimatr` package creators' [website](https://declaredesign.org/r/estimatr/articles/emmeans-examples.html) suggests that `lm_robust` objects can be used with `emmeans`, but I can't see `lm_robust` listed as a supported model on the "Models supported by emmeans" vignette [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html) or the package documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe thar lm_robust objects are an extension of lm, so it uses the emmeans support for lm. In turn, that would imply that the estimates are ovtained via coef(model) and their SEs are derived using vcov(model). So if vcov() returns the robust variances you need, emmeans will use them.

Regarding most transformations, it will work as described in the vignette on transformations. In particular, specifying type = "response" results in the estimates and confidence limits to be back-transformed, the P values to be left alone, and the SEs to be computed by the delta method (but *not* used in the CIs and tests).

#### Additional information

First, I found out that `lm_robust` does not inherit from `lm`; rather, the **estimatr** package incorporates its own support for **emmeans**. Not many details are given, but that developer of **estimatr** must believe that what is provided must be appropriate.

The `scale()` transformation is not built-in, because it is complicated. Just saying we used `"scale"` isn't as simple as saying it is `"log"`, say, because to work with `scale()` results, we need to know what was used to center and divide the results.

The workaround is to create the object that `emmeans()` and its relatives need to invert the transformation; and that is a list of functions of the form returned by `stats::make.link()` or `emmeans::make.tran()`. Here is a function that will serve that purpose:

```
make.scaletran = function(y, ...) {
    sy = scale(y, ...)
    if(is.null(m <- attr(sy, "scaled:center")))
       m = 0
    if(is.null(s <- attr(sy, "scaled:scale")))
        s = 1
    list(
        linkfun = function(mu) (mu - m) / s,
        linkinv = function(eta) s * eta + m,
        mu.eta = function(eta) s,
        valideta = function(eta) TRUE,
        name = paste0("scale(", signif(m, 3), ", ", signif(s, 3), ")")
    )
}
```

To use this, you need to manually specify the transformation since it isn't auto-detected. Here is an example using the `warpbreaks` data already available in R:

```
> warp.lmr = lm_robust(scale(breaks) ~ tension, cluster = wool, 
+     se_type = 'CR2', data = warpbreaks)

> tran = make.scaletran(warpbreaks$breaks)

> emmeans(warp.lmr, "tension", tran = tran)
 tension emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L        0.624 0.619 51   -0.618   1.8666
 M       -0.133 0.181 51   -0.497   0.2301
 H       -0.491 0.219 51   -0.930  -0.0517

Results are given on the scale(28.1, 13.2) (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> emmeans(warp.lmr, "tension", tran = tran, type = "response")
 tension response   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 L           36.4 8.17 51     20.0     52.8
 M           26.4 2.39 51     21.6     31.2
 H           21.7 2.89 51     15.9     27.5

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the scale(28.1, 13.2) scale
```

The code in the OP for the `emmip()` call is not correct, as it uses the specs for `emmeans()`, not `emmip()`.

I will consider adding this scale transformation option to `emmeans::make.tran()` in a future update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the second part, I don't think that `scale()` is a recognised transformation: `Unknown transformation "scale": no transformation done`. I've tried your suggestion and those in the vignette and the SEs, CIs, p-values are always `given on the scale (not the response) scale`. For comparison, if I use `log()` instead of `scale()`, things work as per the vignette.

Comment: You're right. I read the word "transformation" but didn't look at what you used. I'll add to the answer.

Comment: It's very kind of you to write out that function. It works great, thank you. I'll edit my answer to correct the coding mistake in the `emmip()` call. Thanks again.